# member.roles.add(role) is not adding a role in my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
member.send("debug for maintenance")

    var role6 = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == verifi.get(`verifi_role_${member.guild.id}`))
    member.roles.add(role6)
```

This is my code.
(verifi is a quick.db database, this code is running in 'guildMemberAdd')
Any idea why this wouldn't be working? I've confirmed that it's running this code, and it's just not giving the role and not throwing any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize if it's something simple, I'm new to v12.

Comment: How is `member` defined?

Comment: @Lioness100 member is coming from guildMemberAdd ex. `client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {`